# Render animation in video editor does not work (Sequnecer in Post Processing is checked)

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video

This was asked multiple times but the solution doesnt work. I animated a 4 second Loop and now want to make it a 20 seconds video with music. When I click render animation the output is blank and no Progress bar or anything else is to be found. The usual answer is to check Sequencer in Post Processign in the Output Properties but I did that and it didnt help.

[image]

EDIT: I found out. Maybe this is interesting for others.

In the bottum window I clicked on View and then Sequence Render ANimation and I got an error saying Window Size is now dividable by 2, so I changed my output resultion and now it renders fine